# How do I use ajax to automatically refresh my JSF page?

Tags: ajax, jsf

**Scenario**

The Problem I'm having is that I have no clue how to automatically refresh an `<f:ajax>` JSF component. Is there any way to do this without primefaces? I'm stuck only using the resources that JEE6 incorporates (no other libraries). will `<f:ajax>` be able to do this. Is there an attribute that `<f:ajax>` has the will automatically update when the beans value changes?

**Problem:**

When I can only get `<f:ajax>` to work on a button click.

**Desired Goal**

Have `<f:ajax>` automatically refresh every N seconds

Code I'm working with:

**helloAjax.html**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:body>

        <h3>Ajax Example</h3>

        <h:form>   
           <h:inputText id="name" value="#{ajaxBean.name}"></h:inputText>
           <h:commandButton value="Submit">
             <f:ajax execute="name" render="output" listener="#{ajaxBean.name}" onchange="Submit" />
           </h:commandButton>
           <h2><h:outputText id="output" value="#{ajaxBean.sayWelcome}" /></h2> 
        </h:form>

    </h:body>

</html>
```

**AjaxBean.java:**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class AjaxBean
{
    private String name ="";

    public String getName() 
    {
       return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) 
    {
       this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSayWelcome()
    {

       if(name.equals("") || name ==null)
       {
           return "";
       }
       else
       {
         return "From AjaxBean: "+new java.util.Date().getTime() +" "+ name; 
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Or if I'm using Primefaces how do I get this snippet working"*: it'd be helpful if you elaborate the concrete problem in detail instead of letting us guess the problem symptoms. Please update your question to include detail about what exactly happens (not). What exactly happens (not) while debugging the HTTP traffic and the Java code? The first part of your question is by the way overly generic (there are 1000 ways to achieve this) and will likely be ignored as if it was "Not A Real Question".

Comment: @BalusC See revision. That's the best I can do. I have no idea how to have ajax refresh automatically with JSF

Comment: Why did you omit the `<p:poll>` attempt from your question? That's one of the ways. That it doesn't work out for you should instead be asked/elaborated in detail instead of the current one which basically boils down to "Which of the 1000 ways should I use?".

Comment: @BalusC Omitted because this is an external resource. I just need ONE that works without any external dependencies outside of the JEE6 resources. If you know how achieve this with the given code PLEASE do provide ONE way

Comment: @BalusC For having a '1000 ways' to do this, I didn't even receive ONE from you

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to fire event, example:

```
jQuery('#commandButtonId').tigger('click');
```